# How to declare an Array with its dimensions specified by another int[] array. Like float[int[]]?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am creating an API for machine learning in C# to gain a better understanding of how they work. I'm using the same names as Keras uses for simplicity.

In my project, every `Layer` needs to specify its `inputSize` and `outputSize`. If a layer, for example, receives a 10x10 image, it's input size is `new List<int>{10, 10}`. This is passed as a parameter for the constructor of the Layer, as is the output size.

While trying to create a `Dense` layer (fully connected), I found it simpler to constrain the input size to a single array dimension because the weights can be declared as `float[][] _weights = new float[OutputSize[0]][]`. But what if I want to connect a multidimensional matrix as input, and keep some of its format as output?
The results should the the same as flattening the array before, and reverse flattening after. In my model, this would take 3 layers for one!

```cs
    public Dense(List<int> inputSize, List<int> outputSize)
    {
        if (inputSize.Count != 1 || outputSize.Count != 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Input size and output sizes must have only 1 dimension; inputSize has " +
                                inputSize.Count + " and outputSize has " + outputSize.Count);
        }
        Random rng = new();
        this.InputSize = inputSize;
        this.OutputSize = outputSize;
        this._weights = new float[this.OutputSize[0]][];
        this._biases = new float[this.OutputSize[0]];

        for (int i = 0; i < this.OutputSize[0]; i++)
        {
            this._weights[i] = new float[this.InputSize[0]];
            for (int j = 0; j < this.InputSize[0]; j++)
            {
                this._weights[i][j] = (float)(rng.NextDouble()*2-1);
            }
        }
    }
```

The rest of my code already generalizes for multidimensional `Array`, so this constructor is the only bottleneck.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `float[][]` is called jagged array, [multidimensional array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/arrays) is `float[,], float[,,], etc.`. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, for the title, .net has an [Array.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.createinstance?view=net-7.0#system-array-createinstance(system-type-system-int32())) method which accepts an array of int as the size of each dimension.

Comment: `int[] dimensions = new int[] {3, 4, 5}; var result = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(float), dimensions);` to create multi dimensional array (here is 3d array with length 3, width 4 and height 5)

Answer (score 0):

As Dmitry Bychenko answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77360472/how-to-declare-an-array-with-its-dimensions-specified-by-another-int-array-li#comment136381553_77360472) comment, the **hypotetical** `float[int[]]` is implemented in C# like:

```cs
var result = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(float), dimensions);
```

being `dimensions` an array of type `int[]`.

Comment: Mandatory warning here: There's no static typing information, so type errors cannot be caught until runtime.